# Mypy more specific parameter in subclass

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I want to declare a base class with an abstract method that has a typed parameter such that implementing classes can specify a more specific type for that parameter, for example:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Job(ABC):
    pass

class EasyJob(Job):
    pass

class HardJob(Job):
    pass

class Worker(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def run(self, job: Job) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError()

class EasyWorker(Worker):
    def run(self, job: EasyJob) -> None:
        pass

class HardWorker(Worker):
    def run(self, job: HardJob) -> None:
        pass
```

However, mypy understandably complains about this:

```
line 14: error: Argument 1 of "run" is incompatible with supertype "Worker"; supertype defines the argument type as "Job"
line 18: error: Argument 1 of "run" is incompatible with supertype "Worker"; supertype defines the argument type as "Job"
```

Is there any way in Python to facilitate such a structure?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably want [Bounded Parametric Polymorphism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parametric_polymorphism#Bounded_parametric_polymorphism). See also [this section about bounded type variables](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#type-variables-with-an-upper-bound).

In *Worker*, you want to say that your method *run* is generic in the sense that it takes a value of some unspecified type *T* whereas *T* is a subtype of *Job*. The classes derived from *Worker* then substitute *T* for concrete types:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Generic, TypeVar


class Job(ABC):
    pass


class EasyJob(Job):
    pass


class HardJob(Job):
    pass

T = TypeVar('T', bound=Job)


class Worker(ABC, Generic[T]):
    @abstractmethod
    def run(self, job: T) -> None:
        raise NotImplementedError()


class EasyWorker(Worker[EasyJob]):
    def run(self, job: EasyJob) -> None:
        pass


class HardWorker(Worker[HardJob]):
    def run(self, job: HardJob) -> None:
        pass
```

Comment: I get this mypy error twice with the above code:
E1136: Value 'Worker' is unsubscriptable (unsubscriptable-object)